# How to start developing and debugging the Linux Kernel?

Tags: linux, debugging, linux-kernel, kernel, development-environment

I want to start some Linux development for my research. Writing few simple scheduling algorithms and test them. I have few questions:

1) How do you develop for the linux kernel? IDE? How do you  import the kernel files and see how they are related or connected?

2) Once you write your code, how do you simulate/debug it? I mean one can't just build the kernel for 20 - 30 minutes, make a new image and change boot.ini each time. This is a lenghty process plus you can't simulate or debug just observe if it works or not.

3) Is there A guide for starting developing in Linux. I find the lack of documentation surprising

I am developing for ARM-based boards

Excuse my ignorance. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

How do you develop for Linux kernel?

There are many components in the Linux kernel. Typically, kernel is divided into core and driver parts.

- Core includes scheduling, MMU, memory management, process management etc
- Drivers includes file system, networking, peripheral device drivers, USB etc

IDE is not a must to develop kernel code. For kernel veterans, VIM/nano is also OK. The development environment is up to you. If you are new to the kernel code, you want to build the function relationship views, some tools can be helpful:

- Source Insight (Commercial)
- vim + ctags  (http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Single_tags_file_for_a_source_tree)

How to debug it?

There are many Linux favors/distributions. You can use Software emulator or Hardware boards to debug the kernel. Android is based on Linux and there are many mobile phones or development boards that support Android. iOS is also derived from Linux and it is its own debug method.

Where to find the kernel documents?

- For kernel part, there are many readme articles in kernel source tree. e.g. http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/Documentation/debugging-via-ohci1394.txt
  printk is powerful enough for newbies.
- For ARM part, there are many articles in infocenter.arm.com 
  Debugging Linux kernels using DS-5
  http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.den0024a/ch18s03s03.html?resultof=%22%6b%65%72%6e%65%6c%22%20